# Wp Meta query does not work while meta value does

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I have two queries which  I believed should both work because I believe they are exactly the same

The one is as follows ( Works perfectly, and gives me the posts I need )

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type'  => 'vacancy',
    'meta_key' => 'full_or_part_time',
    'meta_value' => 'part_time',
)
```

The other one is as follow : ( Returns all posts, ignores the meta query )

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type'  => 'vacancy',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'full_or_part_time',
            'value'   => "part_time",
        )
    ),
);
```

I cannot figure out why option two does not work. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using `WP_Query()` for the first snippet and `WP_Meta_Query()` for the second one?

Comment: Hi I am using query_posts(), I tested with WP_Query() and it gave me the same results.

Comment: Since your meta query contains only one meta parameter, could you please try: `'meta_query' => array( 'key' => 'full_or_part_time', 'value'  => "part_time" ),`

Comment: @GrafiCode I found the issue, there was function in the functions file that overrode the meta_query input for all post types. Thank you for the assistance